# Failed building wheel error when installing web3 using pip and Python 3.8.2

Tags: web3.py

I have been trying to install web3 using the command pip install web3 but it doesn't work !!!, I have tried so many solutions but nothing works , here is the error that I have, I hope guys you can help me.
at the bigging, it gives this and then right after it just continues to give me red lines of errors
[first page of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNKiq.png)

[image: the second page of e]

Answer (score 2):

The required compiler will be installed in addition to Visual Studio as [build tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, i just install Visual Studio Build Tools [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16)

or from visual studio installer.